# How can I run lldb locally in browser with WebAssembly

Tags: webassembly, lldb

Im building a online editor that can run C++ code. I want to implement a debugger and want to use WebAssembly to deliver it to the users browser and sandbox the environment. I'm wondering how feasible it is to compile something like the lldb source code into web assembly. If not, what are some alternatives I have of implementing a debugger?

I've tried compiling the entire llvm directory into web assembly, but am having trouble with using emscripten to do so.

Comment: One problem you are going to run into is that lldb does not itself actually control processes for debugging.  That's done by the debug stub (debugserver on macOS, lldb-server elsewhere).  debugserver is not installed on the base system, it's also part of the tools, and it requires some fairly sensitive system entitlements, so it has to be explicitly trusted.  Distributing that safely will also be tricky.